# Crystal Reports (2013) - Creating rows dependant on a result

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm creating an inspection report, part of this requires the report to look at a qty, work out 20% of said qty then add required rows to correspond.

SO,

QTY = 10, 20% = 2 
 (I need to automatically add 2 rows) 
 Inspection Report 1 
 Inspection Report 2

Hope this makes sense, 
 And hope its possible

Comment: you want to use a report to add new rows to a data source?

Comment: Hi, I want to add them to the report.

Comment: the report will generate the 20% figure, then I want to add into the same report the rows

Comment: You can use some supress conditions to show and hide the rows when it reaches 20%

Comment: are you selecting a random sample, so the detail section would display 10 rows, but you want to suppress 8 of them?

Comment: Is the number of rows needed potentially unlimited or is there an upper limit to QTY?

Comment: Hope every one had a good Easter holiday!

Comment: CoSpringsGuy - yes the number of rows would be unlimited in theory, but I cant see it getting to the 100 mark. Siva and Beth supressing sounds like a good way, I'm assuming that I would have to add a specific number of rows before I could supress?